# Do obese people have lower lifetime healthcare costs?

Tags: economics, healthcare, obesity

I've always been told that obesity is a drain a country's healthcare system...and it's generally accepted as fact.  In online debates I frequently see reference to this.  I remember seeing news reports on 'The Cost Of Obesity' that say obese people cost the U.S. (as an example) millions or billions each year.

I wanted to give a specific claim - so here is just one of a near-endless supply I could find:

http://www.forbes.com/sites/rickungar/2012/04/30/obesity-now-costs-americans-more-in-healthcare-costs-than-smoking/

> Obese men rack up an additional $1,152 a year in medical spending,
>   especially for hospitalizations and prescription drugs

That seems really straight-forward....but, on the flip side....there seems to be evidence that suggests the opposite.  One study tracked life-time medical expenses from age 20 until death:

http://www.forbes.com/sites/timworstall/2012/03/22/alcohol-obesity-and-smoking-do-not-cost-health-care-systems-money/

> The actual numbers for lifetime from 20 years old medical costs were:
>
> The lifetime costs were in Euros:
>
> Healthy: 281,000
>
> Obese: 250,000
>
> Smokers: 220,000

At first glance - I think it might be possible for both of these statements to be true.  An average living obese man might cost an average of $1,152 per year than an average living non-obese man; but the obese man might die sufficiently earlier so that the life-time cost is lower.

But I'm left unable to determine the actual financial impact.  Is obesity as scapegoat for increasing insurance costs when, clearly, living a healthy life will result in more medical costs....or is obesity really raising all of our bills?

Comment: Hope you don't mind. I edited the title so it reflects the claim more clearly. I hope I haven't misrepresented what you wanted to ask.

Comment: I think it's more complicated than just straight comparison. For example let's assume that healthy vs obese means 20 year delay in spending, and the money is invested at something with 5% interest rate. After 20 years you have +165% of interest.

OTOH, obese, smokers, alcoholics, drug addicts etc. are salvation for any social security systems, as very often they don't live long enough to even get one month of pension.

Comment: If true, it's because they die younger and so incur lest old age costs.